# Android: Keeping data in RAM without affecting battery life

Tags: java, android, android-service

In my application I have a set of data -`Definition` (mostly `Strings`, `Enums`, and flags - i.e. nothing large) that **dynamically** (i.e. cannot be hard coded into the service action) define how the `IntentService` is to handle its input.

My basic problem, is that rather than load these `Definition` structures from their XML file every time an `Intent` is passed to the `Service`, I would like to keep them in memory (as they are small and fast access is desirable due to the service being called very often) and use the `Definition`s sitting in RAM to process `Intents` as the `Service` receives them.

Logically, all I can think of is a permanent background `Service` for which there is a wealth of sources saying that that is a bad idea (which I agree with).

I guess essentially what I am looking for is a way to store this data in RAM until it is needed (like the system Android does with open apps, launchers, etc) and not have any adverse impact on battery life (i.e. the `Service` does **nothing** but hold the data in RAM until called), but be available whenever my `Service` is called?

Is there any possible way that this can be achieved or is the only option a permanent `Service` that I have to manage extremely carefully?

If a permanent `Service` is the answer, will an `IntentService` (configured to be `START_STICKY`) just sit in RAM and not affect battery life until it is passed an `Intent`?

Comment: There is no such thing as a real permanent background service in android. Remember it is a phone first so any service including foreground services can be killed when the phone rings and it is low on memory. This design is intentional otherwise services could hog all memory and your phone would turn into a smart brick.

Comment: Good point, I guess I just have in my head that permanently caching a few kB of the phone's memory for an extended duration in exchange for a quick snappy response all the time seems like a worthwhile tradeoff. But I guess that 'selfish' approach isn't holistically applicable if all apps did it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My basic problem, is that rather than load these Definition structures from their XML file every time an Intent is passed to the Service, I would like to keep them in memory (as they are small and fast access is desirable due to the service being called very often) and use the Definitions sitting in RAM to process Intents as the Service receives them.

First, "the service being called very often" suggests that you may already be causing pain for the user, in terms of CPU and battery utilization, depending upon your definition of "very often". The additional battery cost of this disk I/O will be minimal by comparison.

Beyond that, you are welcome to hold onto this data in static data members. They will be around as long as your process is around. Depending upon what is going on with the device, and depending upon your definition of "very often", this data may be available to you in the next invocation of your service. If not, you just reload from disk. In other words, use the static data members as a cache.

> Logically, all I can think of is a permanent background Service for which there is a wealth of sources saying that that is a bad idea (which I agree with).

Specifically, the incremental battery cost of the disk I/O is not worth tying up the user's RAM all of the time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Commons. My use of "very often" made it sound a bit more dramatic then I meant I think. The service is invoked by the user opening a `Shortcut`, so it is only run when they specifically request it. A key requirement is that I want the completion of this action to be as quick as possible - hence the caching. I think based on your answer a `Service` which hangs around for as long as 'Android naturally allows it' with static members sounds like the best idea.

Comment: @BT: "The service is invoked by the user opening a Shortcut, so it is only run when they specifically request it" -- all the more reason not to worry about the disk I/O. "A key requirement is that I want the completion of this action to be as quick as possible - hence the caching" -- and when you ran performance tests, to determine how long the disk I/O actually takes, what did you learn? "a Service which hangs around for as long as 'Android naturally allows it' with static members sounds like the best idea" -- that's just your `IntentService`, then.